# How to transfer a domain from 101domain to another registrar?

Tags: dns, domain-transfer

A friend of mine bought a domain name on 101domains, and now wants to have his website hosted on my servers. I would like to have full control of the DNS records, and thus would like to change the NS records to point to my DNS server.

I can't find how to do that on their control panel. I can access the listing of DNS records for the domain, but cannot change it. Thus, I would like to transfer it to another registrar, that I know allows to do all these changes.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want to transfer the domain to a new registrar? Or simply point the domain to a nameserver? They are two very different things.

Comment: Well, I actually wanted to point the domain to a nameserver, but can't do it, and their support is not answering my tickets. Thus, I'd like now to transfer the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their FAQ doesn't explain how to Transfer a domain out (what a surprise eh) but there should be somewhere in the Control panel that allows you to possibly unlock the domain then create an authorisation key which you can give to your new registrar.

Why is it that these hosting companies don't answer support tickets? Dreadful level of service. Either have instructions in your FAQ or answer the queries.

Comment: Some don't, as a way to lock you in. Not many will press on even after a ton of frustrations.

Answer (score 5):

1. Login at 101domain.com
2. Go to [their 'Domains' page](https://my.101domain.com/domain.html)
3. Click on the domain in question
4. Buried halfway down that page you'll see a 'Request Authorization Code' link.

Deliberately hard to find if you ask me!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are not asking to transfer the domain but rather gain access to the dns records.

1. Login as the domain owner and select active domains
2. click on the appropriate domain name
3. on the lower right side of the screen will be the dns servers.
4. Click edit DNS servers and make the desired changes.
5. scroll all the way to the bottom and click next.
6. A new screen will show the proposed DNS changes
7. Click next at the bottom again and your changes will be confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Then find domain secret / authorization key and use it for transferring it.Note your domain must be 60 days old for eligibility.